# How to open the attached files from django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

can anyone help me in how to make the attched files opened from django admin website?

this is my code:

IDAttached = models.FileField(upload_to='/documents/%Y/%m/',null=True, blank= True)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see what the user of your django site uploads to the database you need to register your models.py of the app to the admin interface. For instance say you have models.py as below:

```
class ABC(models.Model):

    ABCFILE=models.FileField(upload_to='<path>/%Y/%m/%d')
```

create an admin.py file inside your app folder and the following code:

```
from equipo.<your_app_name>.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(ABC)
```

after this you be be able to see it on your admin interface.

Comment: No module named equipo.APF.models ,,,,, it gives me this error

Comment: Equipo is the name of my project you should replace it with the name of your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set MEDIA_URL correctly in your settings.py you should be able to get an address for those files at my_model.IDAttached.url

Django a runserver should display them for you in development but in production you'll need to configure your web server to display the contents of MEDIA_ROOT itself.